# Autohotkey clipboard variable holding values forever?

Tags: autohotkey

I have the below simple code, which sends keystrokes for text in the clipboard with a 15ms delay in between characters (I use this to traverse huge lists of treeview elements).

Issue: If I have copied 'text1' to clipboard, followed by 'text2', this script outputs 'text1text2' instead of 'text2' alone.

If I reload the script, then it prints 'text2'.

Is there a mistake in the below code, or is it a bug in implementing %clipboard% in Autohotkey 1.1.14.03 ?

```
#v::
textToType=" "
textToType=%clipboard%
LoopCount:=StrLen(textToType)
;StringLen, LoopCount, textToType
Array%LoopCount%:=textToType
loop %LoopCount%
{
theChar:=Array%A_Index%
Send %theChar%
sleep 15
}
return
```

Update: Thanks for pointing out smarter ways of doing this,  but I would still like to figure out what is wrong in the above piece of code.

Update 2: 
The mistake was in my understanding of the AHK syntax. `Array%LoopCount%:=textToType` assigns the whole string value in textToType to the (LoopCount)th **STRING** element of the **STRING** array named 'Array'.

Update 3:
(Thanks @John Y for clarifying)

Actually, there's no "declared" array at all, in a traditional sense. You just have a bunch of individual variables, dynamically created as needed, that happen to have names with numbers at the end. Array1 and Array2 are not elements in some Array object. They are just two completely independent variables. AutoHotkey provides a way to glue numbers onto the ends of names, so you can use them like an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your script doesn't work properly is because you're using a [pseudo-array](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Arrays.htm#pseudo) to store different words from your clipboard.

I've commented up your code to explain what it does:

```
#v::
    textToType  := "" ; Empty variable
    textToType  := Clipboard ; Move clipboard into variable

    ; Get lenght of the word
    ; Used as array index / loop count
    LoopCount := StrLen(textToType)

    ; Put the clipboard in an array at index 'LoopCount'
    Array%LoopCount% := textToType

    ; Loop through the array as many times
    ; as the string is long
    Loop % LoopCount
    {
        ; Retrieve the word at this index in the array
        theChar := Array%A_Index%
        ; Send the whole word
        Send, % theChar
        sleep 15
    }
return
```

Instead of sending each character at a time, you're sending whole words from specific indexes in your `Array` array.

Say you copy the word `Dragon`, that word is 6 letters long. So you'd put that in `Array6`, then you'd loop through your array 6 times using the same variable. At which point the loop would take each index at a time and move it into `theChar`. On your 6th lap in the loop you'd put `Array6` into `theChar` and print the whole word at once.

Then you copy the word `Stackoverflow`. That's going to go into `Array13`, and we're going to loop 13 times. On the 6th lap we're going to print out `Dragon` which is in `Array6`, and then keep going until we reach 13 where we'll print `Stackoverflow` since that is in `Array13`.

So that's why your script isn't doing what you want it to. Hopefully this helps a little.

See the code sample [alpha bravo posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287870/autohotkey-clipboard-variable-holding-values-forever/26291759#26291759), that's the correct way of achieving what you want to do.

Comment: I don't really understand your explanation.If it was printing the whole string in 'theChar' one go , it would have printed the same full sting 'LoopCount' times. Variable assignement and 'Send' is in the same loop, inside the braces. (I agree am new to AHK, it was 2 mins of reading the manual and coding this, but those are basic universal programming rules)

Comment: @dbza: I think you will understand better if you execute your code by hand (with pencil and paper, say) for a few iterations. When you get to a variable, fill it in with the actual value. Notice that when you are at loop iteration 1, unless the word you just stored was 1 character long, that iteration doesn't print anything, because Array1 doesn't exist. In Sidola's example, Array2 doesn't exist either. Only Array6 and Array13 exist. Your code is storing array elements according to input length, and the loop prints each element from the shortest up to the length of the most recently saved.

Comment: Thanks Guys. Indeed that 2 mins of reading the manual in a hurry was my issue.I thought Array%LoopCount%:=textToType meant something like declare an array of characters with LoopCount elements and assign the value in the string textToType . In reality it created an array of strings and put textToType in the Nth string element (LoopCount). I need to familiarize more with the syntax.

Comment: @dbza: Actually, there's no "declared" array at all, in a traditional sense. You just have a bunch of individual variables, dynamically created as needed, that happen to have names with numbers at the end. `Array1` and `Array2` are **not** elements in some `Array` object. They are just two completely independent variables. AutoHotkey provides a way to glue numbers onto the ends of names, so you can use them *like* an array. When you look at the AutoHotkey docs on arrays, pay special attention to the difference between "associative arrays" and "pseudo-arrays". You're using a pseudo-array.

Comment: Thank you so much @JohnY! I might have missed this basic information in that manual page on arrays or they don't have it in there at all.

Answer (score 3):

keep it simple

```
#v::
loop Parse, Clipboard
{
    Send %A_LoopField%
    sleep 15
}
return
```

Comment: Just looked it up http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm But can anyone tell what is worng in my original piece of code ?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a bug in implementation of clipboard assignment in AHK. With the below code, the behaviour of AHK is that everytime the value of `dir` is accessed, AHK fetches the latest value from clipboard, instead of fetching the value of `dir` at the time the script was activated.

```
; Remove all CR+LF's from the clipboard contents:
dir = %clipboard%
sleep 100
dir := StrReplace(dir, "`r`n")
```

EDIT:
To fix this, I added 1 second sleep before clipboard assignment code:

```
sleep 1000
; Remove all CR+LF's from the clipboard contents:
dir = %clipboard%
dir := StrReplace(dir, "`r`n")
```

100 millisecond sleep didn't seem to work.

Accessing value of `dir` now only gives value of last clipboard assignment at activation.